Connection Issue with SQL Server using pyodbc in Azure Data Studio
I am currently using Azure Data Studio to connect to a SQL Server instance. The authentication type I'm using is Microsoft Intra ID with MFA support. I'm able to successfully connect, create tables, and manage schemas within Azure Data Studio.
However, I want to load data into my tables using a Python script executed in Jupyter Lab on my local system. My current connection string looks like this:
import pyodbc

Database connection parameters

    server = 'server'
    database = 'database name'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'

Connection String:
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')

When I attempt to connect using this code, I receive the following error:
InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. (18456)")
How can I modify my Python connection string or approach to successfully connect to the SQL Server using this authentication method?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Get the real authentication error from the SQL Server logs; if you don't understand that error, then [edit] your question to include it.

And which driver are you using?

Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server ********][SQL Server] Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft] [SQL Server *****][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'. (18456)")

If the user doesn't have access to the database or if the provided credentials are incorrect then you may get above error. Make sure user is accessible to the database and provided correct credentials i.e. username and password. As per this article MFA is the default method of login for all azure tenants. So, when you try to connect Azure SQL db with ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication you may get below error:
('FA004', "[FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user '****' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').\r\nError code 0xCAA2000C; state 10\r\nAADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '****'. Trace ID: 9827ec0f-865a-4b15-9c70-207409726100 Correlation ID: 16bf58ec-0c82-45e6-bdbc-9eca4a0a9e11 Timestamp: 2024-08-12 05:46:53Z (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user '****' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').\r\nError code 0xCAA2000C; state 10\r\nAADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '022907d3-0f1b-48f7-badc-1ba6abab6d66'. Trace ID: 9827ec0f-865a-4b15-9c70-207409726100 Correlation ID: 16bf58ec-0c82-45e6-bdbc-9eca4a0a9e11 Timestamp: 2024-08-12 05:46:53Z (0)")

So, use MFA authentication to connect Azure SQL db python
ActiveDirectoryInteractive authentication method using below code:
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net'
database = ',dbName>'
username = '<EntraId>'
auth = 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Authentication='+auth+';UID='+username+';ENCRYPT=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor() 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <tableName>")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

It will connect to SQL db  and read the table successfully from data studio as shown below:

